# Oracle query help needed

Tags: oracle

After doing this below query we will get missing days now i want to add additional filter that is if any of the displayed dates with the below query is saturday and sunday it has to remove those date so those dates should not be displayed can anyone guide me how to extend this filter in the below query..
Below query i got from this forum but along with this query i need some query which will satisfy me the above question. please help me how to modify this query

```
with date_range as (
  select min(the_date) as oldest, 
         max(the_date) as recent, 
         max(the_date) - min(the_date) as total_days
  from your_table
 ),
  all_dates as (
   select oldest + level - 1 as a_date
   from date_range
   connect by level <= (select total_days from date_range)
   )
   select ad.a_date
   from all_dates ad
   left join your_table yt on ad.a_date = yt.the_date
   where yt.the_date is null
   order by ad.a_date;
```

Comment: "max(the_date) - min(the_date) as total_days" is not inclusive -- if total_days from 1st Jan to 2nd Jan is supposed to be "2", add 1 to this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition:

```
and to_char(ad.a_date, 'Dy') not in ('Sat','Sun')
```

- to your `where` clause.

Comment: Better have it like this `to_char(ad.a_date,'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')` otherwise it might not work for different NLS_DATE_FORMATs http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11183